# Splitting/Mapping Cassandra concatenated values into Solr fields

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm using Solr and Cassandra (via DSE).  Here is one entry (row) of data in Cassandra:

```
ORDER_INFO_CF
 -orderHistoryID=1000072459
   -SPECIAL_COLUMN_KEY=0800000002||1294034400000|113942
```

I can index the Cassandra data without an issue, with this schema.xml:

```
<schema name="ORDER_INFO_CF" version="1.1">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.WikipediaTokenizerFactory"/></analyzer>
  </fieldType>
 </types>
 <fields>
    <field name="orderHistoryID"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="SPECIAL_COLUMN_KEY"  type="text" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
 </fields>
```

Of course, having all the data lumped into one pipe-delimited string doesn't help very much.  So I tried to split it using the PatternTokenizerFactory, like this (schema.xml):

```
<schema name="ORDER_INFO_CF" version="1.1">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
  <fieldType name="splitField" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="|" /></analyzer>
  </fieldType>
 </types>
 <fields>
    <field name="orderHistoryID"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="AccountNumber"  type="splitField" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="ActionFlag"  type="splitField" indexed="false"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="CreatedDate"  type="splitField" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="CreatedTime"  type="splitField" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
 </fields>
```

orderHistoryID is still being mapped, but the `SPECIAL_COLUMN_KEY` value is not being split into the four fields described above.  I'm sure that I'm just not doing something quite right with the `PatternTokenizerFactory`.  I've also looked at the `DataImportHandler RegexTransformer`, but that only seems to works with RDBMS and XML imports.

Essentially, my data maps like this in Solr:

```
orderHistoryID=1000072459
SPECIAL_COLUMN_KEY=0800000002||1294034400000|113942
```

And I'm trying to get it to map like this:

```
orderHistoryID=1000072459
AccountNumber=0800000002
ActionFlag=
CreatedDate=1294034400000
CreatedTime=113942
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to solve this problem would be to use [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Usage) . Assuming that you already have an api to read records from cassandra, you will be able to feed it to solr using Solrj.

The other way would be to create a custom POJO and then use . For example -

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

public class CustomRecord {
   @Field
   private String orderHistoryID;
   @Field
   private String AccountNumber;
   @Field
   private String ActionFlag;
   @Field
   private String CreatedDate;
   @Field
   private String CreatedTime;
}
```

and then use

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://HOST:8983/solr/");
server.addBean(customRecord);
```

For more details, refer to [directly adding pojos to solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr).